# RecyclerView error ConcurrentModificationException only API 23 & API 26

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, concurrentmodification, android-8.0-oreo

I get ConcurrentModificationException in my RecyclerView, only in APIs 23 & 26, how can I bypass this?
This is my RecyclerView Setup:

```
private void setUpRecyclerView() {

    int maxIndex = 0;
    if (game.size() < 3) {
        maxIndex = game.size();
    } else if (game.size() >= 3) {
        maxIndex = 3;
    }
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view);
    adapter = new GameCardListMiniAdapter(this, game.subList(0, maxIndex));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ActivityHome.this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
}
```

after I manipulate the data from `game`, I call `recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, true);` and get the error, but only in the afore mentioned APIs, in the rest of the APIs up to API 15 everything works just fine.
This is the stacktrace for API 23:

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa0d2a5a0
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.racu.cardgame, PID: 26900
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList.size(AbstractList.java:360)
    at com.example.racu.cardgame.adapters.cardgameListMiniAdapter.getItemCount(cardgameListMiniAdapter.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3603)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3103)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1446)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:512)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygot
```

This is for API 26:

```
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d2e70a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8e8b510)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.racu.cardgame, PID: 4691
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1057)
    at com.example.racu.cardgame.adapters.cardgameListMiniAdapter.getItemCount(cardgameListMiniAdapter.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3603)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3103)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1446)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:512)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1060)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21998)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-14 18:50:44.793 4691-4691/com.example.racu.cardgame E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Tried to make it work creating the game.SubList outside,with a `for` loop instead of a `SubList`, didn't crash, but `swapAdapter` wasn't being called and the most strange thing is that is working wonderful in my phone, no crashes and the expected behavior.

I really,really apreciate some light.
Regards Ne0R@Cu

Answer (score 2):

The root of this issue is that *List.subList()* does not copy the List:

> /**
>    * **Returns a view** of the portion of this list between the specified
>    * fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.  (If
>    * fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is
>    * empty.)  **The returned list is backed by this list**, so non-structural
>   ...

Then, when you call *size()* on the resulting view, the exception is thrown. I haven't dug into why this happened, but *size()* tries to validate it's current size, which in this case is conflicted between the full list and the view.

So, you can remedy this crash by simply copying the list:

```
List<YOUR_TYPE> trimmed = new ArrayList<>( game.subList(0, maxIndex) );
adapter = new GameCardListMiniAdapter(this, trimmed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

instead of :

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ActivityHome.this);
```

then do the same thing ext

```
 rc.setHasFixedSize(false);//only use this for fixed ammount
            rc.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            rc.setAdapter(dataItemAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but does not work still I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any answer for my question, I ended up creating a `HorizontalScrollView` and adding my views from code to a `LinearLayout` within the `HorizontalScrollView`.